# Moving directories based on their size overall, and then based on the quantity of files within them

Tags: linux, find, move

I’m trying to clean up all of my music folders (and there are a lot) - but rather than delete, I want to move the ones that are empty, or have only a few Mb, or have just a few files in them.

I’ve managed to use the following `find` command to move all the empty directories:

```bash
find . -empty -type d -exec mv {} /share/Container/beetsV2/music/my_empty_folders \;
```

... but I can't seem to work out how to find directories based on size. I thought the following would work, but it doesn’t; it seems to return way more than expected.

```bash
find . -size -5M -type d -exec mv {} /share/Container/beetsV2/music/my_folders_under_5Mb \;
```

When it comes to finding directories with only a few files in them, I can’t seem to find a single command line to do that like the above. Does one even exist?

Answer (score 1):

From `man find`:

> -size n[cwbkMG]
> File uses less than, more than or exactly n units of space, rounding up.

This switch is not relevant for directories *disk usage*.

---

A workaround is to use `bash` to treat all directories from `find` output, to take the size of each of them and `mv` each if the size is less than N MiB:

```
move_dirs_smaller_than() {
    export MAX=$(($1*1024)) # $1 is in MiB
    export path=$2          # $2 /path must be outside of .
    find . -mindepth 1 -type d -exec bash -c '
        read size _ < <(du -sk "$1")
        ((size < MAX)) && echo mv -- "$1" "$path"
    ' bash {} \; -prune
}
```

Remove `echo` statement when the output looks good enough.

#### Function usage for 5MiB:

`/path` should **NOT** be in current directory (or use `find ! ./dir`):

```
move_dirs_smaller_than 5 /path
```

---

Look at `find`'s man page about `-prune`, `-mindepth` and `-maxdepth` depending on your needs.

Comment: Many Thanks @Gilles, is it possible to do all that from a single line entry, so it’s easier for me to call programmatically? If so what would that look like ?

Comment: You can put that in a shell function, that's what they're for

Comment: Yes; better use a `function`. If you insist for a one-liner, edit the directory, test it and remove `echo`: let's go `max=5000 find . -type d -exec bash -c 'read size _ < <(du -s "$1");((size < max)) && echo $max mv -- "$1" "./elsewhere";' bash {} \;`

Comment: Thanks again, although when I remove the word `echo` it doesn’t work and just returns a recurring message of  `bash: 5000: command not found` ?

Comment: Which OS, which shell : need `bash` and paste your current edited line. `echo $SHELL` which output ?

Comment: `-size` works fine for directories, but it only checks the size of the directory, not the disk usage of it and the files within which the OP is wanting.

Comment: Added `function` + _arguments_

Comment: @GillesQuenot, if i do # `echo $SHELL` it returns `/bin/sh` does that help?

Comment: @GillesQuenot - if i put function first `function max=5000 find . -type d -exec bash -c 'read size _ < <(du -s "$1");((size < max)) && echo $max mv -- "$1" "./elsewhere";' bash {} \;` it returns `-sh: syntax error near unexpected token `find'`

Comment: Where I told you `funtion max=5000`?

Comment: I told you to use `bash`

Comment: Hi @GillesQuenot picking this up again after Xmas/new year break - reminder `if i do # echo $SHELL it returns /bin/sh` please advise on next steps based on that output

Comment: If you run `sh` and `bash` is installed, no issue

Answer (score 0):

The GNU implementation of `du` can give you a report of:

- cumulative disk usage (default)
- cumulative size with `--apparent-size`
- cumulative number of files (of any type) with `--inode`

For directories and their contents (unfortunately, it can't include all three in one report).

You can also tell it not to deduplicate hard links with  `-l` / `--count-links`.

It's one of the rare ones whose output you can post-process reliably as it's got a `-0` / `--null` option to output NUL-delimited records.

So if you're on a GNU system, you could do:

```bash
xargs -r0a <(
  du --inode --null --count-links | # count inodes
    tac -s '' | # reverse the output so parents are shown before children
    perl -0lnse '
      if (
        m{^(\d+)\t(.*)}s &&
        $1 < $max &&
        rindex($2, "$last_moved/", 0) < 0 # not a subdirectory of the last moved
      ) {
        print($last_moved = $2);
      }' -- -max=10
  ) echo mv -it /path/to/destination --
```

Which would move the directories that contain (recursively) fewer than 10 files (of any type including directory, and including the directory itself).

Replace `--inode` with `--apparent-size --block-size=1` (or `-b` for short) to consider the cumulative size instead of number of files. Same without `--apparent-size` for disk usage (you'll want to update `-max` accordingly).

Remove the `echo` if happy with the result to actually do it.

All of `-r`, `-0`, `-a`, `--inode`, `--apparent-size`, `-l`, `--count-links`, `tac`, `-b`, `--block-size`, `-t` are non-standard GNU extensions few of which have been added to other implementations of those standard utilities, so don't expect that to work outside GNU systems unless you've installed GNU `coreutils` and `findutils` there. Since you've used the linux tag though, there's a fair chance you are on GNU system.

To consider both number of files and cumulative size, you could use GNU `find` which has a `-printf` predicate which can report file type, and size and do the sums by hand:

```bash
xargs -r0a <(
  find . -depth -printf '%y %s %p\0' | perl -0lsne '
    if (m{^(\S+) (\d+) ((.*)/.*)}s) {
      my ($type, $size, $file, $parent) = ($1, $2, $3, $4);
      $count{$parent} += ++$count{$file};
      $size{$parent} += $size{$file} += $size;
      unshift @dirs, $file if $type eq "d";
    }
    END {
      for $dir (@dirs) {
        if (
          $size{$dir} < $max_size &&
          $count{$dir} < $max_count &&
          rindex($dir, "$last_moved/", 0) < 0
        ) {
          print $last_moved = $dir;
        }
      }
    }' -- -max_count=10 -max_size="$(( 5 * 1024 * 1024 ))"
  ) echo mv -it /path/to/destination --
```

For the disk usage instead of apparent size, replace `%s` with `%b` which you'll have to multiply by 512 (replace `$2` with `$2 * 512` above) to get the disk usage in bytes.